# Monitor FARGATE and EC2 Container using cAdvisor

Tags: docker, containers, monitoring, cadvisor

I have launched some container using EC2 and some using FARGATE and I am monitoring those containers using cAdvisor, But I am not able to differentiate the containers between EC2 and FARGATE.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cAdvisor doesn't seem to be [adding support for fargate](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2142) as of now. I wrote a simple exporter to do the same for Fargate and EC2 type containers. It's available here: https://github.com/Spaced-Out/ecs-container-exporter